# function containing for are not expanded inline

Tags: c++

When I am running this C++ code in my Turbo C++ compiler it is giving me following errors:

1. **Line 52**: function containing for are not expanded inline
2. **Line 74**: Compound Statement Missing
3. **Line 74**: Declaration terminated incorrectly.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10
#include<stdlib.h>

class queue
{
int s[MAXSIZE],front,rear,i;
public:
  queue(){front=-1;rear=-1;}


 void insert(int val)
   {


        if(rear==MAXSIZE-1)
            cout<<"queue is full";

        else
           if (front==-1)
         {
              front=0;
           }
          rear=rear+1;

          cout<<"\n"<<" Enter the info" ;
            cin>>s[val];

    }
  void del()
 {
      if(front==-1)
          cout<<"queue is empty";

       else
       cout<<"item deleted"<<s[front];
          if(front==rear)
                front=rear=-1;
         else
               front=front+1;


   }
  void traverse ()
   {
      if(front==-1)
          cout"queue is empty";

       else
       {
          for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
                   cout<<"\t"<<s[i];

        {
    }

 };
 void main()
{
linklist l1;

l1.insert(10);
l1.insert(20);
l1.insert(30);
l1.traverse();
l1.del()     ;
l1.insert(40);
getch();
}
```

Comment: when I am compiling I am getting error saying "function containing for are not expanded inline"

Comment: Maybe they aren't... So what? But "error"? I highly doubt any compiler would consider this an "error". What's the full text of the error message?

Comment: take that function out of the class body.

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Upgrade to a more modern compiler Turbo C++ is over 20 years old.

Comment: [http://i.imgur.com/bbyDDD0.png](http://i.imgur.com/bbyDDD0.png)

Comment: okay, so compiler is old buy any solution so I can run it in this compiler.

Comment: Very many problems, but the baddest of the bunch are: `cout"queue is empty";` should be `cout<<"queue is empty";` and the braces mish-mash at the bottom of the traverse function.

Comment: Fix those two up so the compiler's not getting totally confused and you'll have 20, 25 more errors.

Comment: fixing it, thank you.

Comment: BTW, the `main` function returns `int`.  **Always.**

Comment: I suggest you split into at least 2 files:  one file containing the class declaration (without function implementation) and the second containing `main` and the class function implementations.

Comment: @Aumkar Thakur: So, it is not an "error", it is a *warning*. In this case the warning is purely informational. The compiler is *informing* you about the fact that one of your functions is not expanded inline. That's OK, compilers never guarantee anything about inline expansion. Just ignore the warning or disable it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should compile, but it will not work as intended. I'm not going to try to fix it because the logic is too broken and handled better by reading up on queues in a text before continuing.

I cannot be certain this compiles in Turbo C++. I haven't used Turbo C++ since the 90's, and even then I just used it to compile C code.

Explanations are embedded in the comments to keep everything in one chunk.

```
#include<iostream> // don't need the .h
#include<conio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10
#include<stdlib.h>

// need to specify namespaces. Don't pull in the whole namespace unless you
// know exactly what you are doing. JUst use the parts you need or explicitly
// state with every use eg. std::cout << "queue is full";
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class queue
{
    int s[MAXSIZE], front, rear; // no need to define i here. Only used in
                                 // the traverse method and has no need for
                                 // persistence
public:
    queue()
    {
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }

    void insert(int val)
    { // this function almost certainly does not work logically
      // a queue adds to one end and takes from the other. This allows the
      // caller to put an element anywhere in the queue, destroying
      // whatever value was in that slot.

        if (rear == MAXSIZE - 1)
        { // always use all of the braces while learning. You can take the
          // training wheels off when you know how to do it safely.
            cout << "queue is full";
        }
        else if (front == -1)
        {
            front = 0;
        }
        rear = rear + 1;

        cout << "\n" << " Enter the info";
        // using \n in place of std::endl may have unexpected consequences
        // with respect to flushing. std:: endl means end the line and write the
        // output. In this case,display on the console. \n means end the line and
        // write when you feel like it. Result is the user prompt may not be
        // written before it stops for user input on the next line.

        cin >> s[val];
    }

    void del()
    { // this function's logic is also broken.
        if (front == -1)
        {
            cout << "queue is empty";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "item deleted" << s[front];
        }
        if (front == rear)
        {
            front = rear = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            front = front + 1;
        }
    }

    void traverse()
    {
        if (front == -1)
        {
            cout << "queue is empty"; // missed the <<. This broke the for loop
                                      // because the braces weren't used and
                                      // the compiler choked rather than giving
                                      // a reasonable error message.
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++) // defined the i removed earlier
            {
                cout << "\t" << s[i];
            }
// braces here were completely messed up.
        }
    }
};

void main()
{

    queue l1; // was linklist rather than queue

    l1.insert(10);
    l1.insert(20);
    l1.insert(30);
    l1.traverse();
    l1.del();
    l1.insert(40);
    getch();
}
```